# Calling a Django file as a startup service in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-14.04, init

I'm a newbie here. How can i use a python file in my Django application that will be used in startup for my Ubuntu server. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/).

Comment: Can it call a manage.py and from that call a function for the startup? Like manage.py shell then calling a function. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Can i use this `python manage.py shell < service.py` in supervisor?

Comment: No, you can't use `manage.py shell`. Have a look at django-extension`s runscript command: http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either write your own management command as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) and then call it during/after boot, like:

`python /var/www/myproject/manage.py myscript somearg`

The command could look like this:

```
from polls.models import Question

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete stale questions'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        questions = Question.objects.filter(stale=True).delete()
```

Don't forget to activate your virtual environment beforehand if you use one, or it will not find django or other pip packages.

Or you use the 3rd party plugin [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html) which provides the `runscript` command needs less boilerplate and maybe more beginner friendly to write:

```
python manage.py runscript delete_all_questions --script-args staleonly

from polls.models import Question

def run(*args):
    questions = Question.objects.filter(stale=True).delete()
```

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) for options on how to add your script to be autorun on boot

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me. By the way, i use [django-extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).